# How to regard $ \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ as graded ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, graded-rings

I heard $ \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/((xy-z^2)$ can be regarded as grade ring, but how ?

$ \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$ can be regarded as graded ring by decomposition$ 
\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]＝ \bigoplus_{d\geq 0} A_d$, where $A_d＝${all degree d homogeneous polynomial}, $A_d$ clearly satisfies $A_b・A_c⊆A_{b＋c} $ for all $b,c≧0$.

But in the case $ \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/((xy-z^2)$, I'm having trouble how to decompose $ \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/((xy-z^2)$ into $\bigoplus_{d\geq 0} A_d$, which satisfies $A_b・A_c⊆A_{b＋c} $ for all $b,c≧0$ ? What can I take as $A_d$ ?

Comment: No, my case is  limiting polynomial ring, I want to describe explicitly what $A_d$ is, in the case of this question, $ \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$

Comment: The link that Greg Martin gives contains an explicit construction of the $A_d$. Not sure what could be more explicit.